# are there something like isClicked in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a div element, with img element in it.

`onclick` of `div` i make one function, and `onclick` on `img` - another. but when i click on `img` it make the first function too, because the `img` is in `div` element.
so, i think, that if there were something like `isClicked`, onclick of div i can just verify, if img is **Not** clicked ...

(i can write a logic, and verify it by so,for example onclick of img i can add a class to somebody... but maybe there is a function for it?)

Thanks

Update:

```
<div class="left_expended" style="position: relative;">
    Լեզուներ
    <img src="images/new_page.gif" id="new_lang" title="Լեզու ավելացնել" />
</div>
```

and jquery

```
$(".left_expended").live('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass("left_collapsed");
            $(this).removeClass("left_expended");
            $(this).next("div .container").slideUp(400);
        });

        $("#new_lang").click(function()
        {
            alert("something");
        });
```

onclick of img it makes first function too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the click on the `<img>` from going up to the `<div>` using [`event.stopPrpagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), like this:

```
$("#new_lang").click(function(e) {
  alert("something");
  e.stopPropagation();  //don't bubble!
});
```

What happens *normally* is that [events bubble](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), the `click` on the `<img>` "bubbles up" to the `<div>` afterwards...unless you stop it, which is exactly what [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) does.  This way anything activating your `$("div").click(...)` is anywhere inside *except* the image, because a click there wouldn't go up anymore, which seems to be what you're after :)

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/bind/ talks a bit about how they work. In particular:

> Returning false from a handler is
>   equivalent to calling both
>   .preventDefault() and
>   .stopPropagation() on the event
>   object.

Answer (score 0):

i think now, but you can add it adding this to your code:

```
$("div,img").click(function(e){$(this).addClass("isClicked");e.stopPropagation();});
```

and then, you can play with CSS or jQuery, with the class ".isClicked"

Hope that helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [stopPropagation](http://help.dottoro.com/ljgfjsxd.php) in the click event for the `img` so it won't propagate further to the div click event. Also look at http://api.jquery.com/event.isPropagationStopped/.

Grz, Kris.